# flowplayer not working on firefox

Tags: firefox, flowplayer

Iam using flowplayer to embed an flv file in a page. It works just fine in IE8,Chrome and Opera, but firefox refuses to show anything. There is just blank space where the file is supposed to be. Is this a known issue ?

Flowplayer version : 3.1.4
Firefox version : 3.5.5 
Firefox extensions : Java Quick starter,RealPlayer Browser record plugin.

js code:

```
flowplayer("flvContent", "flowplayer-3.1.5.swf", "somefile.flv");
```

Comment: Are there any exception messages in the Error Console in FireFox?

Comment: Nope.A few warnings but unrelated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out the problem.
The div in which the file was to be embedded did not have height and width specified earlier, when the height and width were added it's works on firefox as well.

Earlier markup:

```
<div id="flvContent"></div>
```

Modified markup:

```
<div id="flvContent" style="width:80%;height:300px;"></div>
```

Comment: I'm using Flowplayer 3.2.6 with Firefox 7.0.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.8 and this solution worked for me.