# Flowplayer (3.1.4) not working on Portable Firefox (1.7.3.0)

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, flowplayer, portable-applications

My problem is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873215/flowplayer-not-working-on-firefox) and [this](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/775766)

The difference is I am trying to make it work on [portable-Firefox](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable)

Here's the relevant js/html code:

```
<table id="videoBox" border="0" width="541px" height="350px" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0" >
  <tr>
    <td width="521px" valign="middle" align="center">
      <div id="video" style="width:521px; height:324px;"></div>   
      <script language="JavaScript">
      var bgImg = 'url(../theme/img/video-overlay-en.jpg)';  

      flowplayer('video', '../theme/flowplayer-3.1.4.swf', {

        onLoad: function() {
          this.setVolume(100);    // set volume to 100% 
        },

        onBeforeFullscreen: function() { return false; },
        buffering: false,
        debug: false,

        canvas: {
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
          backgroundGradient: 'none'
        },

        plugins: {
          content: {
            url: '../theme/flowplayer.content-3.1.0.swf',
            backgroundImage: bgImg,
            height: 95,
            width: 521,
            padding: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            opacity: 1.0
          },
          controls: null
          },
          clip: {
            url: '../media/44/01.flv',
            autoPlay: true,
            autoBuffering: true,
          },
          play: {
          opacity: 0,
          label: null, 
          replayLabel: null
        }
      });
      </script>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that the video doesn't play even though there seems to be the "buffering symbol" at the start for a moment. I have obviously tried the solution that worked for the links above (viz. modify the code in div tag), but that didn't work for me. Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. It's an old version of flowplayer as you can see but that should not make any difference imho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me:

When you are trying to view flash video (.flv in my case) from your local hard drive the flowplayer needs some security settings which is basically to allow the content in the directory containing the flash content. Here's the link explaining details:

[FlowPlayerBasics](http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/installation/index.html)

Scroll down to the bottom of the page and click on the link provided to edit your flash player security settings.